# Cannot see a CABasicAnimation when called from within a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, for-loop

I have an animation which randomly moves a tile on a grid which works fine. However when I call in a for loop you dont see any of the animation. How do i get this to work?

```
    for (i=0; i<10 ; i++){
        // Call animation function
         sleep(.5);
    }
```

Animation looks like

```
CABasicAnimation *move;
[move setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[button.layer position]]];
CGPoint toLoc = [button.layer position];
// modify toLoc by +/-70px in x/y direction 
[move setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toLoc]];
[move setDuration:0.5];
[button.layer setPosition:toLoc];
```

I appreciate any advice/comments : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start an animation, you need to let control return back to the system in order to see it perform the animation. Inserting a `sleep` is almost never the right thing to do in today's world of multi-threaded systems. It is certainly the reason that you are experiencing this issue.

Instead, you might consider doing something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<10 ; i++){
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(i * 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Call animation function
  });
}
```

---

Given that your sleep time is the same as your intended animation duration, it looks like you're just trying to repeat your animation, though. Instead, try just adding this line and removing the loop:

```
[move setRepeatCount:10];
```

You'll also need to instantiate the object and actually add the animation to the layer.

```
CABasicAnimation *move = [[CABasicAnimation alloc] init];
[move setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[button.layer position]]];
CGPoint toLoc = [button.layer position];
// modify toLoc by +/-70px in x/y direction 
[move setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toLoc]];
[move setDuration:0.5];
[move setRepeatCount:10];
[button.layer addAnimation:move forKey:@"position"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the repetition logic should be handled by the animation function you are using.
If you are using CAAnimation you can use it's callback
"- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag"
to check if you should and then start a new animation or not from there.